# Codeigniter - No result after sending jQuery post data

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I'm working on a signup form using jQuery's AJAX and Codeigniter PHP framework, but the codeigniter doesn't matter that much, if you see weird `echo form_open();` or other weird things, don't worry, they're all codeigniter.

Okay, here's my problem with the code. I tried simple post using jquery below (in the php code everything else is omitted and added a simple echo 'hello, world!'; function, and it works / giving me a hello, world!):

```
 $.post( 'ajax_signup_username' ,function(result){

                $(span_error).html(result);

            } );
```

But when I passed a post data in it, it doesn't work (doesn't output any result,note that I'm using the **full PHP code** written *below-below*):

```
$.post( 'ajax_signup_username', {php_username_error:username_value} ,function(result){

                $(span_error).html(result);

            } );
```

I've tried searching SO, but the solutions provided didn't solve this. Any idea what's wrong?

**Here are the full codes:**

Following is the html code:

```
<body>

<?php $attr = array( 'onsubmit' => 'return final_val()' ); echo form_open('formValidation/signUp',$attr); ?>


<p>Username: <input type="text" onBlur="username_val()" value="<?php echo set_value('username')?>" name="username" maxlength="50" /><span name="username_error"><?php echo form_error('username'); ?></p></span>


<p>Email: <input type="text" onBlur="email_val()" value="<?php echo set_value('email')?>" name="email" maxlength="50" /><span name="email_error"><?php echo form_error('email'); ?></p></span>


<p>Password: <input type="password" onBlur="pass_val()" value="<?php echo set_value('pass')?>" name="pass" maxlength="50" autocomplete="off"/><span name="pass_error"><?php echo form_error('pass'); ?></p></span>


<p>Password Confirm: <input type="password" onBlur="pass_val()" value="<?php echo set_value('passconf')?>" name="passconf" maxlength="50" autocomplete="off" /><span name="passconf_error"><?php echo form_error('passconf'); ?></p></span>



<p><input type="submit" value="SIGN UP!" name="signup"/></p>


</form>



</body>
```

Following is the php code:

```
function ajax_signup_username(){

    $username = $_POST['php_username_error'];

    $uniqueUn = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM iowfiwefwmember WHERE username=:username");

    $uniqueUn->bindParam(':username', $username);

    $uniqueUn->execute();

    $count1 = $uniqueUn->fetch();

    if( $count1 == FALSE ){

        echo 'USERNAME AVAILABLE!';

    }else{

        echo 'USERNAME IS ALREADY USED!';

    }

}
```

Following is the javascript code:

```
function username_val(){

        $.ajaxSetup({ cache : false });

            username_value = $("input[name='username']").val();

            span_error = "span[name='username_error']";

            //$(span_error).load('ajax_signup_username', {php_username_error:username_value}); <-- also doesn't work [ $.ajaxSetup() is set to POST ]

            $.post( 'ajax_signup_username', {php_username_error:username_value} ,function(result){

                $(span_error).html(result);

            } );

    }
```

Comment: Do you get a JavaScript error?  What happens when you make a post request to the URL directly?

Comment: Also please don't bother the PDO codes, the point is that after sending a post data in the parameter, it doesn't work.

Comment: @ExplosionPills  The web developer toolbar in firefox gave me a POST Server Error, but I tried navigating the code in the browser and it exists.

Comment: how are you routing the url 'ajax_signup_username' to the function? Is this some CodeIgniter magic?

Comment: @PHPForLife navigating in the browser is not enough .. you have to make the same post request using the browser or some other user agent.

Comment: @vansimke Yes, it is. When you navigated into http://localhost/foo/bar/ajax_signup_username in the browser, it exists.

Comment: @ExplosionPills How do I do that?

Comment: @ExplosionPills form_open() automatically generates a post method in the form

Comment: @PHPForLife if it can be done in ajax it can be done some other way.  You're going to have to figure this out, or you'll never be able to test ajax requests.

Comment: @PHPForLife If FireFox is griping, then there is apparently something wrong in the url. Try hardcoding the full url (localhost/foo/bar/...) into the $.post call and see if that does what you want it to.

Comment: ExplosionPills & vansimke - Sorry for wasting your time on this, turns out this is actually a codeigniter issue, thank you anyway! Cheers! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After long hours of doing dumb faces in front of my laptop, I found out that this **IS** a codeigniter issue, I turned on CSRF protection which caused the problem. After turning off CSRF feature, it works just fine, make sure not to repeat the same mistake, youngsters! Cheers! :D

Comment: I wouldn't recommend CodeIgniter for new developments though. Since Ellislab decided not to support it anymore, it took almost 2 years for some bug fixes be realeased from version 2.1.3 to 2.1.4. But yeah, for me the CSRF features also caused problems.